# iOS : Date format - 20-Sep-2012

Tags: iphone, ios, date

I want to display the date in the format "20-Sep-2012" from the string "2012-11-22 10:19:04". How can i do this? Is there any in-built method for iOS?

Comment: yes you can set your date format to dd-mmm-yyyy

Comment: How can I do? Can you provide the code?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
NSString *myString = @"2012-11-22 10:19:04";
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";     
NSDate *yourDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:myString];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MMM-yyyy";
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:yourDate]);
```

your log will print like this. `22-Nov-2012`

Comment: what if I need `2012-11-22 at 11:23`? how do I add that `at` inbetween

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 You can put `at` inside the format. `yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm` This should work. You can put text inside single quotes to get it back.

Answer (score 6):

Try this,

```
NSString *originalDateString = @"2012-11-22 10:19:04";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];//2012-11-22 10:19:04
```

Then use it to parse the date string as,

```
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:originalDateString];
```

You can create a new dateformatter to print in the new format or just reuse the existing one as,

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];//22-Nov-2012
NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"Date in new format is %@", formattedDateString);
```

Comment: mate change //20-Sep-2012 to 22-Nov-2012 mate.. :)

Comment: @ParasJoshi, Thanks. I was just quoting his question there, just for his understanding. Just to let him know that the equivalent format is that.

Answer (score 2):

Accepted answer from (@Dinesh Raja) in **Swift 3:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
    print(self.getFormattedDate(myString: "2012-11-22 10:19:04"))
}

func getFormattedDate(myString: String) -> String{
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        let yourDate = dateFormatter.date(from: myString)!
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
        return dateFormatter.string(from: yourDate)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    NSString *str = @"2012-11-22 10:19:04";

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString: str];

    dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];

    NSString *convertedString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    NSLog(@"Converted String : %@",convertedString);// Print Log (Output) is 22-Nov-2012
```

see my blog with this all information [My Blog Link with this types of method](http://parasjoshi3.blogspot.in/2012/01/convertstringtodatedatetostring.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with following way

```
      NSDateFormatter *dfTime = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
      [dfTime setDateFormat:@"yyyy--MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
      NSDate *dtTime = [dfTime dateFromString:<Your string>];
      NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
      [df setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy"];
       <Your result string> = [df stringFromDate:dtTime];

Where <Your string> = @"2012-11-22 10:19:04" & 
<Your result string> will be your new string
```

Enjoy Programming